# Polymorphism: store objects

Tags: polymorphism, java-8

I was testing around polymorphism, and I came up with below code:

```
public abstract class Animal {

}


public interface Hunter {

}

public class Cat extends Animal implements Hunter {

}


public class Tiger extends Cat {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //n1
    }

}
```

I placed on n1:

```
ArrayList<Tiger> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new Cat());
```

But it fails to compile: I think that it does because Cat is parent of Tiger, and Tiger can only store its children which at the moment it does not have any.

Am I overlooking the real cause of this issue?

Comment: I am not taking about collection, I am just curious whether I am wrong or not  with my statement, which is more related to  inheritance.

Comment: @Cubancoffee out of curiosity, why you have not accepted any answers till now?Your profile says you have asked 8 question but you havent accepted any. Does none of them answer all your quries?

Comment: A `Cat` is not a `Tiger` and a list of tigers can’t contain a cat. It doesn’t matter whether “Cat is parent of Tiger” or not. All that matters is that `Cat` is not a subtype of `Tiger`. But do you really need us to get confident that a cat is not a tiger?

Answer (score 3):

Compilation error is because you are violating [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

> It states that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then
>   objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e.,
>   objects of type S may substitute objects of type T) without altering
>   any of the desirable properties of that program (correctness, task
>   performed, etc.).

In your case, you are using super-type (`Cat`), where sub-type (`Tiger`) is expected - i.e., in `myList.add(...)`.  This is not allowed.